# Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) at 0x00000000 (code=2)

Tags: android, osgi, runtime-error, apache-felix, libc

While using a OSGi Platform on Android i got this errormsg:

[image: Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) at 0x595302e0 (code=2)]

Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) at 0x595302e0 (code=2)

I don't think that my app needs that much space in memory or need a lot of computation power.
Its just the OSGi Platform with 20 Bundles.

My app is always restarting after that.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Hi m getting same error.. any luck ? libc(16581): Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) at 0xab5a4068 (code=2), thread 16590 (FinalizerDaemon)

Comment: no, sorry to say. no progress.

Comment: ok :( thnks :) ... can u plz tll me where exactly u gt ths error ?

Answer (score 1):

Even I too found a similar problem and happens to be (code=128) with about fault. Seems to be a data alignment error. To solve this issue, I tried putting a code something like this:

```
    *Data = (*Data)(Temp+i) becomes     
    Temp1 = *(Temp+i);     
    *Data = Temp1;
```

Before and into the function call and passed back the data using same above method. It happens that NDK Compiler works differently some how. And NDK was used to code mix of c and c++.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It caused by a png file in the drawable folder. I just went to see, what the largest picture is, and I found it, deleted it, and replaced it with a more smaller one, and the problem has gone.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with [Data Alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment), as is shown by the [error code](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/realtime/v1r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rt.doc.10%2Fuser%2Fsighand.html).  Some part of your code or the code in the library you're using probably fails to put data structures in the right place - however, this can be caused by a lot of things, such as a function that is supposed to return something but doesn't.