# Android Fatal Signal 7 (SIGBUS)

Tags: java, android, segmentation-fault, sigbus

I'm getting a few SIGBUS (7) and SIGSEGV (11) crashes that I am having difficult tracking down.

The thread that appears to be causing the crash is primarily used for loading images to be displayed which makes sense since the logs indicate something failing with the SkJPEGImageDecoder.

I re-use memory for `Bitmaps` in accordance with this [guide](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html)

Could it have something to do with that?

LogCat output:

```
05-20 13:46:09.775: A/libc(419): Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) at 0x0000001e (code=1), thread 520 (ImageLoaderExec)
05-20 13:46:09.875: I/DEBUG(172): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
05-20 13:46:09.875: I/DEBUG(172): Build fingerprint: 'google/occam/mako:4.4.2/KOT49H/937116:user/release-keys'
05-20 13:46:09.875: I/DEBUG(172): Revision: '11'
05-20 13:46:09.875: I/DEBUG(172): pid: 419, tid: 520, name: ImageLoaderExec  >>> com.package.name <<<
05-20 13:46:09.875: I/DEBUG(172): signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 1 (BUS_ADRALN), fault addr 0000001e
05-20 13:46:09.975: I/DEBUG(172):     r0 0000001e  r1 00000001  r2 00000000  r3 0000001e
05-20 13:46:09.975: I/DEBUG(172):     r4 78d38758  r5 00000000  r6 78be9b28  r7 00000000
05-20 13:46:09.975: I/DEBUG(172):     r8 78d38758  r9 00000001  sl 790818d4  fp 00000001
05-20 13:46:09.975: I/DEBUG(172):     ip 401ab8b0  sp 79080fe8  lr 40179e49  pc 4002e558  cpsr 000b0010
05-20 13:46:09.975: I/DEBUG(172):     d0  0000001100000016  d1  000000060000000c
05-20 13:46:09.975: I/DEBUG(172):     d2  0000000a0000000a  d3  0000000a0000000a
05-20 13:46:09.975: I/DEBUG(172):     d4  000d000e000f000b  d5  000300060009000b
05-20 13:46:09.975: I/DEBUG(172):     d6  000a000a000a000a  d7  000a000a000a000a
05-20 13:46:09.975: I/DEBUG(172):     d8  3f8000003f800000  d9  bf50624dd2f1a9fc
05-20 13:46:09.975: I/DEBUG(172):     d10 3ff8151824c07946  d11 3fd34413509f79fe
05-20 13:46:09.975: I/DEBUG(172):     d12 3ddb7cdfd9d7bdbb  d13 0000000000000000
05-20 13:46:09.975: I/DEBUG(172):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
05-20 13:46:09.975: I/DEBUG(172):     d16 0000000000000000  d17 000004df0000098e
05-20 13:46:09.975: I/DEBUG(172):     d18 000000090000000b  d19 0000000300000006
05-20 13:46:09.975: I/DEBUG(172):     d20 0000187e000011a8  d21 000014c300001712
05-20 13:46:09.975: I/DEBUG(172):     d22 0000000a0000000a  d23 0000000a0000000a
05-20 13:46:09.975: I/DEBUG(172):     d24 000092c00000b890  d25 000038b60000678c
05-20 13:46:09.975: I/DEBUG(172):     d26 0000fcec0000b890  d27 0000d79e0000eeb4
05-20 13:46:09.975: I/DEBUG(172):     d28 0000000f0000000b  d29 0000000d0000000e
05-20 13:46:09.975: I/DEBUG(172):     d30 0019001c001e0016  d31 0006000c00110016
05-20 13:46:09.975: I/DEBUG(172):     scr 68000013
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172): backtrace:
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):     #00  pc 00003558  /system/lib/libcutils.so (android_atomic_inc+8)
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):     #01  pc 00077e45  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (AndroidPixelRef::AndroidPixelRef(AndroidPixelRef&, SkColorTable*)+40)
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):     #02  pc 0007497d  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):     #03  pc 0008f8f5  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkBitmap::allocPixels(SkBitmap::Allocator*, SkColorTable*)+28)
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):     #04  pc 000ed979  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkJPEGImageDecoder::onDecode(SkStream*, SkBitmap*, SkImageDecoder::Mode)+312)
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):     #05  pc 000eb0e1  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkImageDecoder::decode(SkStream*, SkBitmap*, SkBitmap::Config, SkImageDecoder::Mode)+36)
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):     #06  pc 00075201  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):     #07  pc 0007548f  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):     #08  pc 0001dbcc  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):     #09  pc 0004e123  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):     #10  pc 00026fe0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):     #11  pc 0002dfa0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):     #12  pc 0002b638  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):     #13  pc 00060581  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):     #14  pc 000605a5  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):     #15  pc 0005528b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):     #16  pc 0000d170  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):     #17  pc 0000d308  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172): stack:
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):          79080fa8  3f800000  
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):          79080fac  78d38758  [anon:libc_malloc]
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):          79080fb0  00000001  
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):          79080fb4  790818d4  [stack:520]
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):          79080fb8  00000001  
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):          79080fbc  40048bf9  /system/lib/libc.so (malloc+12)
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):          79080fc0  40540f90  /system/lib/libskia.so
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):          79080fc4  404a42e9  /system/lib/libskia.so (sk_malloc_flags(unsigned int, unsigned int)+8)
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):          79080fc8  78d38758  [anon:libc_malloc]
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):          79080fcc  40446719  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkMallocPixelRef::SkMallocPixelRef(void*, unsigned int, SkColorTable*, bool)+32)
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):          79080fd0  00000000  
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):          79080fd4  78d38758  [anon:libc_malloc]
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):          79080fd8  00000000  
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):          79080fdc  78be9b28  [anon:libc_malloc]
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):          79080fe0  00000000  
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):          79080fe4  40179e31  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (AndroidPixelRef::AndroidPixelRef(AndroidPixelRef&, SkColorTable*)+20)
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):     #00  79080fe8  00000000  
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):          ........  ........
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):     #01  79080fe8  00000000  
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):          79080fec  78be9b28  [anon:libc_malloc]
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):          79080ff0  79081848  [stack:520]
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):          79080ff4  790818d4  [stack:520]
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):          79080ff8  00000000  
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):          79080ffc  40176981  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):     #02  79081000  790818d4  [stack:520]
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):          79081004  79081848  [stack:520]
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):          79081008  00000000  
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):          7908100c  0002bf20  
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):          79081010  40176925  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):          79081014  79081848  [stack:520]
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):          79081018  00000000  
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):          7908101c  0000012c  
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):          79081020  787e3f60  [anon:libc_malloc]
05-20 13:46:09.985: I/DEBUG(172):          79081024  404298f7  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkBitmap::allocPixels(SkBitmap::Allocator*, SkColorTable*)+30)
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172): memory near r4:
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78d38738 00000210 0000001a 0000000a 00000001  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78d38748 4c2d6e65 2d6e7461 00005355 00000053  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78d38758 401aa3a8 00000001 405521c0 7e90b008  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78d38768 00000000 075bcd15 00000000 4052ef1c  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78d38778 00000100 7e90b008 3f800000 00000000  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78d38788 01010100 0000001a 00000000 04030201  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78d38798 08070605 790b0a09 00000050 00000073  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78d387a8 24306830 062b0806 07050501 18860130  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78d387b8 70747468 6f2f2f3a 2e707363 69726576  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78d387c8 6e676973 6d6f632e 08064030 0501062b  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78d387d8 02300705 74683486 2f3a7074 5256532f  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78d387e8 75636553 472d6572 69612d33 65762e61  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78d387f8 69736972 632e6e67 532f6d6f 65535256  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78d38808 65727563 632e3347 00007265 000006c3  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78d38818 74d87ab8 00000000 00000000 00000000  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78d38828 00000000 00000000 0000001c 01000080  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172): memory near r6:
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78be9b08 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78be9b18 00000274 0000009d 0000009d 00040106  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78be9b28 00000030 00000032 7880b298 78d37070  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78be9b38 00000000 00000000 3f6c5f93 c1d80000  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78be9b48 00000000 00000000 3f800000 000000c0  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78be9b58 00000030 0000001a 0000003c 00000013  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78be9b68 7693f0d8 00000040 0000000d 00000013  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78be9b78 78bdab08 ffffffff 79ad4c10 00000033  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78be9b88 6e614c5b 696f7264 65742f64 732f7478  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78be9b98 656c7974 6570532f 68436c6c 536b6365  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78be9ba8 3b6e6170 003b7400 00000030 00000033  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78be9bb8 00130182 03020200 03060305 030a0308  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78be9bc8 030f030c 02130211 03180315 021a0319  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78be9bd8 031f031c 03230321 00000324 0000011b  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78be9be8 31ca8130 0609300b 06045503 53550213  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78be9bf8 15301731 04550306 560e130a 53697265  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172): memory near r8:
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78d38738 00000210 0000001a 0000000a 00000001  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78d38748 4c2d6e65 2d6e7461 00005355 00000053  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78d38758 401aa3a8 00000001 405521c0 7e90b008  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78d38768 00000000 075bcd15 00000000 4052ef1c  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78d38778 00000100 7e90b008 3f800000 00000000  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78d38788 01010100 0000001a 00000000 04030201  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78d38798 08070605 790b0a09 00000050 00000073  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78d387a8 24306830 062b0806 07050501 18860130  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78d387b8 70747468 6f2f2f3a 2e707363 69726576  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78d387c8 6e676973 6d6f632e 08064030 0501062b  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78d387d8 02300705 74683486 2f3a7074 5256532f  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78d387e8 75636553 472d6572 69612d33 65762e61  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78d387f8 69736972 632e6e67 532f6d6f 65535256  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78d38808 65727563 632e3347 00007265 000006c3  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78d38818 74d87ab8 00000000 00000000 00000000  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     78d38828 00000000 00000000 0000001c 01000080  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172): memory near sl:
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     790818b4 00000001 00000000 79469c18 00000001  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     790818c4 00000000 00000000 401aa3f8 79081a70  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     790818d4 401aa2f8 00000002 78be9b28 0002bf20  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     790818e4 401aa310 00000001 3f800000 0002bf20  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     790818f4 00000000 00000000 40d0000d 787e3f60  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     79081904 401aa400 00000002 787e3f60 00000000  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     79081914 00000000 401aa3e8 00000001 41466f00  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     79081924 79081c94 00000000 00000000 00000000  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     79081934 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     79081944 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     79081954 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     79081964 00000000 79081a70 00000000 75d5f008  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     79081974 78887d14 00000000 79081a70 00000000  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     79081984 414c958b 46750248 415181f0 00000064  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     79081994 41492e24 00000038 00000000 41513c74  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     790819a4 46750248 a1d00009 6d3f98c0 00000000  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172): memory near ip:
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     401ab890 402aa39d 402aa3e1 402ab78d 402aa451  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     401ab8a0 402ab44d 402ab729 402aa351 4002e570  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     401ab8b0 4002e550 40456485 400752c0 402aa7f9  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     401ab8c0 404564b7 402ab4b1 400c0173 402aa61d  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     401ab8d0 40096919 4028b6e1 4005b2dc 400c00cb  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     401ab8e0 400c34f1 400c074d 40015f31 40015e81  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     401ab8f0 4005d0dc 4005b660 40066bf1 400c3c75  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     401ab900 400c07b1 4003740d 402aaf61 402aaff5  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     401ab910 402aafa5 402aaf19 402ab235 402ab2a9  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     401ab920 402ab319 402ab081 40096919 40096927  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     401ab930 402ab519 408942e0 408947f8 408953a0  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     401ab940 40895364 40895350 4089533c 4089513c  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     401ab950 40895114 408950ec 408950d8 408950c4  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     401ab960 408950b0 4089509c 40895088 40895060  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     401ab970 4089504c 40895038 40895024 40894fe8  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     401ab980 40894fc0 40894f98 40894f70 40894ee4  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172): memory near sp:
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     79080fc8 78d38758 40446719 00000000 78d38758  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     79080fd8 00000000 78be9b28 00000000 40179e31  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     79080fe8 00000000 78be9b28 79081848 790818d4  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     79080ff8 00000000 40176981 790818d4 79081848  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     79081008 00000000 0002bf20 40176925 79081848  
05-20 13:46:09.995: I/DEBUG(172):     79081018 00000000 0000012c 787e3f60 404298f7  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     79081028 405402d0 00000001 00000000 00000004  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     79081038 00000001 4048797d 00000000 4045c3bf  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     79081048 79081848 787e3f60 00000001 4054ebd8  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     79081058 79081548 4045c4a3 4098c201 0000012c  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     79081068 0000012c 00000000 00000000 00000001  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     79081078 00000001 00000000 00000001 00000000  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     79081088 790810cc 00000000 00000000 4048a0bd  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     79081098 405f1290 405f13f0 405f1304 405f12f0  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     790810a8 00000069 00000000 0000003f 00000000  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     790810b8 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000002  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172): code around pc:
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     4002e538 e1910f9f e080c003 e1812f9c e3520000  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     4002e548 1afffffa e12fff1e e1a03000 f57ff05f  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     4002e558 e1930f9f e2801001 e1832f91 e3520000  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     4002e568 1afffffa e12fff1e e1a03000 f57ff05f  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     4002e578 e3e02000 e1930f9f e080c002 e1831f9c  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     4002e588 e3510000 1afffffa e12fff1e e1a03000  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     4002e598 f57ff05f e1910f9f e000c003 e1812f9c  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     4002e5a8 e3520000 1afffffa e12fff1e e1a03000  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     4002e5b8 f57ff05f e1910f9f e180c003 e1812f9c  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     4002e5c8 e3520000 1afffffa e12fff1e 6883b508  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     4002e5d8 47984608 2140ea6f ea801840 eb023290  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     4002e5e8 ea831302 bd082093 2203b5f8 46046943  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     4002e5f8 43726846 0f92ebb3 0076d923 46302104  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     4002e608 ec50f7ff b1e04605 1e772200 6821e011  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     4002e618 3022f851 6858e00a e00cf8d3 0c00ea07  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     4002e628 102cf855 f84560d9 4673302c d1f22b00  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172): code around lr:
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     40179e28 6ab26a49 e94cf7c8 447b4b09 60233308  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     40179e38 42a86b70 4630bf08 30046360 ea18f7c5  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     40179e48 f8846425 46205044 f88464a5 bd7c503c  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     40179e58 0003056a b10b6b43 47706c18 47706c00  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     40179e68 4618e000 2b006b43 f890d1fb b9022044  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     40179e78 47706401 4ff0e92d b085460e 46914605  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     40179e88 6a09a802 f7c769b2 9b02ef00 ea5f9f03  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     40179e98 d1297ad3 7fe7ebb3 e01bd126 46214628  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     40179ea8 e914f7c8 b3384680 f7c5204c 463bea12  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     40179eb8 46424629 0210e88d f7ff4683 4659ff77  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     40179ec8 46304652 eba6f7c6 fffaf7d6 f7c44630  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     40179ed8 e011ef1e 46396828 22c0f8d0 47904628  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     40179ee8 28004604 e007d1da 46284905 24004a05  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     40179ef8 447a4479 fc9ff7d6 b0054620 8ff0e8bd  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     40179f08 00019a62 00026d01 4604b570 4615460e  
05-20 13:46:10.005: I/DEBUG(172):     40179f18 f7ff6880 4631fb0b f7ff462a 6963ffab
```

As per this [document](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/realtime/v1r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rt.doc.10%2Fuser%2Fsighand.html), it appears that SIGBUS 7 is a data misalignment issue, and SIGSEGV 11 is a write to inaccessible memory.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077791/fatal-signal-7-sigbus-at-0x00000000-code-2)

Comment: Thanks, so now I know that it is a data alignment issue - still not sure to fix it though!

Comment: I've put answer below.please accept if its useful to you.Cheers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your misalignment is at address  0x0000001e.  That's a very peculiar address-  it's almost certain to be wrong.  Most likely you're passing in a null pointer somewhere and the C library is trying to either do an array access into it at 30 bytes in, or it thinks its a class and is trying to access some member variable 30 bytes in.  Either way I'd put null checks around anything that could even remotely call into the image libraries, and put isRecycled checks around any bitmap objects to find where you're passing in bad values.

Comment: I do have null and isRecycled checks right before I pass in the bitmap to the BitmapFactory (using inBitmap in the options), though I wonder if something is not as thread-safe as I think and the bitmap gets recycled just after it's using it for a new object.

Answer (score 3):

Its Data alignment issue.Your code is not able to put used data structures in computer's right memory successfully,that caused this issue

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077791/fatal-signal-7-sigbus-at-0x00000000-code-2) link explains this fact correctly.

Comment: Your link has gotten me closer to the answer, but I still don't know exactly why I am getting a SIGBUS/SIGSEGV